# My json keys are getting converted to lowercase once I POST it via RestSharp

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

Here is my code :

```
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

    request.AddJsonBody(new
    {
       

        AccountName= "Some account name",
        AccountStatus= true
    });

    request.AddParameter("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8", ParameterType.RequestBody);

    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

    response = client.ExecutePostAsync(request).Result;
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ToString());

}
```

And Response I am getting is : `400  (Bad Request)`

And then from the server log , I got to know that above code does not maintain Camel case of json Keys. It sends as `accountname` instead of `AcconutName`. Same for `AccountStatus`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RestSharp uses the default options for [JSON serialization in the Web context](https://restsharp.dev/serialization.html#json). You can change these for the client:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web);
options.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
client.UseSystemTextJson(options);
```

The above sample still uses the default options for web, but removes the PropertyNamingPolicy that is responsible for serializing property names as camel-case.